# parse matrix and mapped math-function in array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have a given array, built like this:

```
[[0,2,0,1], 
  0,5,0,0], 
  1,0,1,3]]
```

(for the readability)

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
      array(4) {
          [0] => int(0)
          [1] => int(2)
          [2] => int(0)
          [3] => int(1)
      }
  [1]=>
      array(4) {
          [0] => int(0)
          [1] => int(5)
          [2] => int(0)
          [3] => int(0)
      }
  [2]=>
      array(4) {
          [0] => int(1)
          [1] => int(0)
          [2] => int(1)
          [3] => int(3)
      }
}
```

This input can vary as you can imagine, in length and heights and numbers, but not in the semantic.

I'd like to "map" a simple function, which does some basic math, which should calculate as follows:

> If there are 0's in the the columnn, ignore all further values (values before are still added). Otherwise add all values to a sum.

in my example above, I have to add:

`2 + 5 + 1`

- the 1st row has `0`'s in the first 2 lines, so we don't add the 1.
- 2nd row has 2 + 5 (7), the `0` afterwards doesn't matter
- 3rd row same as 1st one
- 4th row *only* adds 1 (before the `0`, the 3 afterwards is ignored).

I tried to iterate through the given matrix with nested foreach-statements like this:

```
foreach($matrix as $k => $v) { // $v = 0,1,1,2 ... 
    foreach($v as $lineValues) {
        var_dump($lineValues);
    }
}
```

This gives me an output of:

`int(0)
int(1)
int(1)
int(2)
int(0)
int(5)
int(0)
int(0)
int(2)
int(0)
int(3)
int(3)`

I thought about counting the elements in each row and divide this result afterwards to rebuild the array and to compare if there are 0's or not.
If there is a 0, all further additions wouldn't be important, so I'd jump to the 2nd values with incrementing `$j` ...

```
$lineValues][$i][$j]   // (1st row, 1st value) 
$lineValues][$i+1][$j] // (2nd row, 1st value) 
...
```

That didn't help me that much. I also tried to `explode` each line to build an easier-to-read array with `explode("],", $v)`, but that didn't do the trick either.

Keeping all this in the back of my head, I thought about mapping a function to this, but this is where I'm stuck. I guess (correct me if I'm wrong), that such a function should be the wisest choice, when it comes down to performance?

Comment: Is there ever a time where a # in the matrice will be greater than 9?

Comment: @luminoslty possibly, yes.

Comment: Is input of type string or array? You said string and then later stated it's an array. If it is an array then given input should cause a syntax error. Please provide the right input and its type.

Comment: My bad, @revo. The param / input is of the type "array". I'll correct that right now

Comment: Couldn't you just remove the brackets & explode by `,` then iterate over it? You know that every 4th # is in the same column.

Comment: @luminoslty this might change though. It might be 5 rows and 2 columns in the next example.

Comment: True. You could count until the first closing bracket to get the # cols in a row. Also have you tried the SPL Iterator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are possibly cleverer ways to do it, but it works.

```
function parse($matrix)
{
    $sum = 0;
    $sum_detail = array();

    $lineLength = count($matrix[0]);
    for($i = 0; $i < $lineLength; $i++)
    {
       foreach($matrix as $line)
       {
           if($line[$i] == 0) break;
           else $sum += $line[$i];
       }
    }

    echo $sum;
}
```

The idea is to sum first element for line #1, #2, #3 ..., then second element, then third, etc. [Working demo here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/30bd0eb568f22e48f62477bbcd1f1a15e7610a15)

Answer (score 1):

You could iterate over each element and blacklist its column id if the element is `0`.

PHP code (See [live demo here](https://3v4l.org/80pD5)):

```
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    foreach ($row as $columnId => $columnValue) {
        if ($columnValue == 0) {
            $blackListedColumns[] = $columnId;
            continue;
        }

        if (!in_array($columnId, $blackListedColumns)) {
            $entries[] = $columnValue;
        }
    }
}

print_r($entries);
```